# Google analytics tracking for Virtuemart in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, virtuemart

Can someone PLEASE help me to install or point me in the right direction to figure out google anaytics tracking within Virtuemart and Joomla!?!?!

I have the Artio plugin installed and it sends the most inconsistent data you could imagine. So much so that I can't seem to figure out where the problem is occurring. It will report a certain product purchase and then I will attempt to emulate the transaction and it sends nothing. It reports maybe 1 transaction out of 5 or more.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the right site for this question, but since you asked, I use this -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-stats/13732